# How to override / change AngularJS value of value provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to override value-

```
angular.module("data", []).value('apiBase', '/api1/data')
```

at runtime, I tried to modify it with-

```
angular.module("data").value('apiBase', '/someotherapi/data')
```

in some service/controller, but it failed, it didn't override the value of apiBase.

I tried to inject `apiBase` in my controller and change it.

```
angular.module('data').controller(function(apiBase){apiBase = '/someotherapi/data'})
```

it failed.

Then I tried change the apiBase defination to an object like

```
angular.module("data", []).value('apiBase', {"api_base_url":"/api1/data"})
```

then modifying it in controller:

```
angular.module('data').controller(function(apiBase){apiBase.api_base_url = '/someotherapi/data'})
```

It works. so my question is:
why `angular.module('data').value('samekey', 'newvalue')` cannot override the value?
why cannot modify the value when it is just a string/number (primary type. the second try).
In my opinion `Value` provider is singleton, it should change.

Comment: Doesn't feel right to change a module level service/provider/value inside a controller as it would change it for all. If the value has to change it's easier to just wrap it in a service and have setter/getter. Wouldn't make sense to allow an initialize singleton to be overwritten when the app is running.

Comment: Changing the value of an injected dependency during the run phase is almost never the right approach. If you're trying to pass state between controllers/services/etc, consider using [events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please read the documentation on how the [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) works in AngularJS.

Basically, AngularJS application is created in two phases - *configuration phase* and *run phase*. All configuration code, like registering a `.value()` with the special `$provide` service, is done during *configuration phase*. Once that phase ends, no more configuration can be done and the *run phase* begins, where your main module is bootstrapped to the DOM, controllers and services are instantiated, etc. This allows the dependency injection to work in a sane, deterministic manner (requesting an injectable by its ID always returns the same thing for the same ID).